# Facebook plugins stop to working all of a sudden

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-apps

All my facebook plugins and applications stop to working all of a sudden and there hasn't been any code change.

I am testing it with basic like plugin...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

and it responds the error: "The like plugin requires an href parameter".

Additionally all my pages with js sdk responds code 500 error (I have seen on network traffic) on: https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=1676941575883919&domain=herbalista.co&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FTlA_zCeMkxl.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1a652f94595dd6%26domain%3Dherbalista.co%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fherbalista.co%252Ff1e8d0e7e9e8b74%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

I had no problems until today, everything is set up correctly...

[image: App Domains]

And i even set a Valid OAuth redirect URIs:
[image]

Here my js sdk:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1676941575883919";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and here the plugin:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="100%" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

My php-sdk seems to work ok.

Is this a temporary bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have found some more details, i even could not see any comments(fb plugin) in no one page; so i decided to check my plugins under a different ip and for my surprise i realised that everything is ok, it seems fb banned my ip.